# To love a person u must know him first. No love at first lay

Tags: meaning, phrases

Someone I care about very much sent me this. Please help me to know what it means. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No love at first lay is a pun: the original expression is: No love at first sight.

A lay=to sleep with a person, i.e. have sexual intercourse with him or her.